# Should headlines on a social media link post be similar to the article headline on the website to help gain ranking?

Tags: seo, facebook, social-media, title

If I have a website where news articles are posted - basically a headline, copy and image - and I want to drive traffic towards this via Facebook, will using the same headline on both main site and Facebook help with rankings for key phrases in Google?
For instance, look at this post on website:

[image: An article titled 'Love saved Ricardo from drugs, despair']

Now I create a Facebook page as such:

[image: A post titled 'Love saved Ricardo from living in gutters']

Would it be better to have the Facebook post headline also read "Love saved Ricardo from drugs, despair"?

Also, would it be better to leave the URL in the Facebook post rather than having it load the data and then deleting it?

Comment: I would try and match the two titles semantically so that they are complimentary/similar and yet perform well in terms of engagement and CTR. Each social media would have a slightly different audience and therefore motivation can change from app to app and search. I do not use social media enough to be more specific, however, Google+, LinkedIn, Twitter, and Facebook do have different audiences that you should pay attention to. For example, LinkedIn is more professional while Twitter is more trendy.

Comment: Love saved Ricardo from living in gutters.